# SignalR - storing client information

Tags: signalr

I've started experimenting with SignalR. I've been trying to come up with a flexible way of storing information about each connected client. For example, storing the name in a chat app rather than passing it with each message.

At the moment, I have a static dictionary which matches the connectionId to an object which contains these properties. I add to this dictionary on connection, and remove on disconnection.

The issue I'm having is that I don't seem to get all disconnect events. If I close a tab in Chrome, the disconnect seems to go through. However, if I rapidly reload a tab, the disconnect doesn't seem to occur (at least not 'cleanly'). For example, if I reload the same tab over and over, it'll tell me my dictionary has multiple items when it should - in theory still be one.

Is there a standard way of storing this kind of per-connection information? Otherwise, what might be causing the issue I'm having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually handling connection id data correctly.  Ensure that you are only instantiating your user data in OnConnected and uninstantiating it in OnDisconnected.

When spamming refresh on your page there are situations which result in the OnDisconnected event not being triggered immediately.  However you should not worry about this because SignalR will actually time-out the connection and trigger the OnDisconnected event after a designated timeout (DisconnectTimeout).

If you do come across scenarios where there is not a 1-to-1 correlation for OnConnected and OnDisconnected events (after a significant amount of time) make sure to file a bug at https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues.

Lastly if you're looking at doing some advanced chat mechanics and looking for some inspiration check out [JabbR](http://jabbr.net), it's open source!

https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes thanks, this helps a lot. Always nice to hear I'm done it correctly! I didn't know about the timeout - is this configurable? 

Also, how would I need to handle the OnReconnect event?

Comment: Yup! GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout.  For Reconnect you should check to see if your user exists, if it does then do nothing, if it does not then add it =).

Comment: Checking if the user exists - does this mean whether an entry with the provided connectionID exists? I'm still a bit fuzzy on what a connection *really* represents, what its lifetime is, etc. I'll give the docs a full read.

Comment: A connection represents a client.  When I'm saying check if a user exists you can do a look-up in your static dictionary of users.  On a side note, I'd recommend using a ConcurrentDictionary =)